# Anchor Links Not Working On Current Page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use anchor tags in wordpress on my main menu. I am creating the menu through the menu editor in wordpress. I have added my anchors to my page exactly how I want and have tested that the links for example **mywebsite.com/about-us/#executive-team** work correctly.

And they all work as I want them to when I paste the link in the browser address bar.

The links also work when I click on the menu item.

Here is my problem: the anchor links DO NOT work when I click on them from the actual page that has the anchor point on it. For example, if I click on **mywebsite.com/about-us/#executive-team** from mywebsite.com it works great. If I click on **mywebsite.com/about-us/#executive-team** from mywebsite.com/about-us the link does not go anywhere.

Any suggestions. I need the anchor links to work no matter what page they are being clicked from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash from the URL:

```
mywebsite.com/about-us#executive-team
```

The trailing slash is looking for another page. It works fine from an external page, but on the page itself, the slash throws off the browser.